# Extract Text Sections from a Cell

Tags: string, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Given a cell with text pulled from HTML in a format like this:

> OA-1
>
> Interpret products of whole numbers, e.g., interpret 5 × 7 as the
> total  number of objects in 5 groups of 7 objects each. For example,
> describe a  context in which a total number...
>
> - More
>
> OA-2
>
> Interpret whole-number quotients of whole numbers, e.g., interpret 56
> ÷ 8  as the number of objects in each share when 56 objects are
> partitioned  equally into 8 shares, or as a number ...

Goal: extract a list of header identifiers so that output looks like this:
OA-1,OA-2...

I've pulled data via the `=importhtml` function as shown in the two examples on this [MWE sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1blka-IoFEasy7AvdKkH4erlgdBWyX0x_MpeFAyPp9EQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Noting that `char(10)` is a return character, I'm thinking of code something like this
psuedocode:

```
Left(Cell_with_text,number_of_characters = find(first char(10))-1)&","&"find_next_heade"+\r
```

Another approach might me to make a library of all the headers (eg, "OA-1,OA-2...") and somehow find each instance in the cell, maybe with a find function in an array?

### **Assumptions**

- The headers could have between 3 and 7 characters.
- Headers do not always start with the same letter.
- Headers do always have a dash, but it could be anywhere from the 2nd to the 2nd to last position.
- There is always a char(10) after each header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula Splits all of them at once, then just keeps the 1st column (which is your desired output).  Then do the JOIN().

```
=JOIN(", ",INDEX(SPLIT(importhtml("https://contentexplorer.smarterbalanced.org/target/m-g3-c1-ta","list",3),CHAR(10)),,1))
```

[Here is a sample sheet, viewable to all in perpetuity.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ImGCvls9eDG8omZh9xlHy60nSoq4nvFCtgz2lHOvs60/edit#gid=1470978195)

Comment: I can see that you split on char(10) which returns an array including each section, and I'm following the join to get the array into a single cell, but I'm getting lost seeing how an index that pulls everything in the first column returns the headers only.

Comment: In fact, trying the same index split formula on the output of the importhtml function (instead of using the importhtml inside the index split) results in pulling only the first result (as shown on cell A7 of the lovely example provided by @mattking).

Comment: @Zediiiii INDEX() acts as a defacto "ARRAYFORMULA()"  To see how it works in pieces, use ARRAYFORMULA() around the SPLIT() before the INDEX.  I will demo on the sample sheet in a tab called MK.Demo

Comment: great demo, that certainly answers my question. However, I'm still wondering why the `ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(importhtml(...))` function outputs a two-dimensional array, whereas the `ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A2)...` function (the same thing but referencing a cell instead of `IMPORTHTML()` directly) now shown on the demo2 sheet tab outputs a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @Zediiiii Because cell A2 is a formula that joins the importhtml() into only "one value" whereas the importhtml() on it's own is an array of 4 values.